# What is "idiom" in classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, word-request, phrase-request

What would be an idiomatic way to say "idiom" and "idiomatic" in classical Latin?
One could perhaps use the Greek loan word *idiōma* (neuter), but I feel there should be a more Latin way of putting it.
I did not find classical attestations of this loan word.
It is perfectly acceptable to use several Latin words if necessary, but a subordinate clause would feel like too heavy structure for such a thing.

You can either coin something new and explain why it is good classical style, or provide a classical use example.

Comment: My "back-of-the-envelope" thought is that Latin *proprius* might be good for Greek *idios*, giving something like *propriamen*, but that feels artificial.

Comment: In French, *gallicisme* means an idiomatic French form, I don't know if there is an equivalent for Latin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found some examples of classical use of *ĭdĭōma* and *ĭdĭōtismus* by some Latin grammarians (both are Greek loan words):

- **ĭdĭōma, ătis, n. ( ἰδίωμα )**

> - *Grammatici Latini*, Flavius Sosipater Charisius, liber V, “[de idiomatibus](http://kaali.linguist.jussieu.fr/CGL/text.jsp?topic=de%20idiomatibus,%20elocutionibus,%20differentiis%20et%20synonymis&ref=379,1-470,21%20B)” (found *via* the [Gaffiot dictionary](http://gerardgreco.free.fr/spip.php?article43))
>   *idiomata quae sunt nostri sermonis innumerabilia |quidem debent esse.* etc.
> - [*Commentum in Horati Epodos*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=idiom), Pomponius Porphyrio 2.39.6, 2.47.4 (found *via* [PHI](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=idiom))
>   *Potest autem utique accidere idioma.*
>   *Hoc quoque autem ad idioma rusticae simplicitatis pertinet, hornum uinum bibere.*

- **ĭdĭōtismus ou -os, ī, m. ( ἰδιωτισμός )**

> - *Controversiæ*, L. Annæus Seneca Major, [liber II](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/seneca.contr2.html), 21 (found *via* the [Gaffiot dictionary](http://gerardgreco.free.fr/spip.php?article43) and PHI)
>   *HISPO ROMANIVS bello idiotismo usus est: dixerunt, inquit, amici: 'eamus ad raptae patrem, hoc curemus; illud domi est.'*
>   *Idiotismos est inter oratorias virtutes res quae raro procedit*…
> - Marcus Fabius Quintilianus, *Institutio Oratoria* 8.3.22.2 (found *via* [PHI](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=idiotism))
>   *Unde interim grati idiotismi †de quo†, qualis est ille apud M. Tullium: 'pusio qui cum maiore sorore cubitabat' et 'Flauius qui cornicum oculos confixit', et pro Milone illud 'heus tu Rufio', et 'Erucius Antoniaster'.*

Comment: You can also see the 4th volume of Keil’s grammars: https://archive.org/stream/grammaticilatini04keil#page/602/mode/2up

Comment: Thanks! The second word you suggest makes me think more of idiotic than idiomatic use of language, but perhaps the ancients would not have thought so. (I wrote this comment yesterday but forgot to send it. Oh, well...)

Comment: `idiotikon` is a technical term in (Belgian) Dutch, used specifically for dictionaries of regional idiom. I can imagine there are similar words for similar concepts in other Western languages.

Comment: Our word "idiot" derives from a Greek word meaning roughly, vulgar, unskilled, ignorant. I guess "yokel" would be a good translation. So "ĭdĭōtismus" would presumably have meant the kind of language used by such a person: yokel-speak.